# KPSS test in Python with statsmodels

Tags: python, stationarity

I would like to check in Python if a time series is stationary.

I have the following variables:

```
a=np.array([1.003012239,0.995837317,0.991792465,0.993738715,1.000136408,1.004957838,0.995088793,1.000531886,1.00143537,1.003889035,1.004658898,1.003711617,0.994557676,0.991662887,0.992302628,0.992792462,0.994133425,0.997536602,0.995960497,0.992017887,0.99488757,0.990362752,0.996352057,0.994968345,0.993520863,0.994104962,1.000447895,1.005445277,1.011772957,1.013039826,1.019727253,1.016825566,1.008725197,1.005445369,1.003563463,1.005377785,1.01072587,1.010346654,1.008413377,1.005546011,1.001052823,0.998857681,0.994767545,0.990747206,0.988371175,0.982914264,0.986643638,0.982919942,0.984692671,0.980432691,0.986828709,0.984054208,0.988766968,0.987441925,0.991099369,0.989995711,0.990568126,0.984789505,0.985196248,0.984891746,0.984746046,0.984661782,0.978884805,0.979713677,0.979167321,0.974811897,0.977393481,0.982376619,0.97924222,0.974481279,0.977585868,0.973161074,0.966899486,0.970482829,0.970259303,0.97105061,0.972169657,0.973376288,0.974506912,0.978655566,0.971687782,0.97439732,0.977876729,0.981506689,0.97899537,0.978846162,0.975741014,0.979691005,0.976921972,0.9839724,0.986569951,0.978874855,0.980391674,0.981838628,0.980304904,0.98427629,0.98774266,0.986387649,0.992338709,0.987040481,0.989676188,0.997811347,1.003985588,1.003828511,1.00396324,1.007250616,1.008406173,1.005581674,1.008912871,1.009220581,1.010317329,1.0099428,1.013983824,1.012932302,1.01400313,1.011387613,1.003332088,1.00726453,1.013002544,1.012628872,1.009568047,1.004751804,1.008003951,1.012936508,1.006705544,1.00645366,0.999519766,1.001680744,0.998888514,1.001962737,1.000795944,0.995407906,0.993319404,0.996602724,0.9995274,1.003011738,1.000375468,0.997955496,0.994060991,0.985310911,0.987984741,0.98652249,0.993117265,0.99242731,0.989948947,0.993996742,0.996215462,0.99363282,1.00173927,0.996364265,0.990249931,0.987877018,0.986972521,0.9903954,0.993379668,0.992358754,0.995775269,0.989837547,0.987029773,0.99539723,0.989888201,0.985175306,0.986251479,0.983693111,0.982366752,0.980083272,0.983644383,0.982121759,0.989413654,0.983920457,0.982002322,0.988705902,0.989947353,0.989635859,0.983320379,0.985445367,0.981808402,0.983196725,0.986474996,0.988462091,0.983237143,0.978854648,0.985174226,0.992534321,0.992219069,0.985587029,0.985277684,0.988620159,0.996753957,1.001169859,1.003130493,1.002978347,1.008847119,1.014419572,1.016437865,1.012990502,1.00795451,1.01642283,1.020446142,1.026619133,1.033643269,1.027428771,1.02605641,1.019056673,1.023166283,1.025069343,1.026171101,1.021452628,1.016972442,1.015802822,1.018750933,1.021877223,1.018550378,1.012927289,1.003718314,1.000746611,1.003299949,1.004840452,1.001959563,1.002812043,0.998036306,0.999988102,0.998475172,1.001151768,1.001170702,1.004929264,1.001012253,1.001263538])
b=np.random.choice(range(-1000,1000),10000)
c=np.array(range(1,1000))
```

If I do the `kpss` test of `statsmodels` what I get is:

```
print '======a======'
print kpss(a)
print '======b======'
print kpss(b)
print '======c======'
print kpss(c)
```

And the result is:

```
> ======a======
> 
> Warning (from warnings module):   File
> "...", line 82
>     warn("p-value is greater than the indicated p-value ", InterpolationWarning) InterpolationWarning: p-value is greater than
> the indicated p-value (0.24205088752544565, 0.1, 15, {'5%':
> 0.463, '1%': 0.739, '2.5%': 0.574, '10%': 0.347})

> ======b====== 

>(0.085996053575288708, 0.1, 38, {'5%': 0.463, '1%': 0.739, '2.5%': 0.574, '10%': 0.347})
>
> ======c======
> 
> Warning (from warnings module):   File
> "...", line 80
>     warn("p-value is smaller than the indicated p-value", InterpolationWarning) InterpolationWarning: p-value is smaller than
> the indicated p-value (4.4456302303149693, 0.01, 22, {'5%': 0.463,
> '1%': 0.739, '2.5%': 0.574, '10%': 0.347}) [ 0.99667882  1.32908899
> -0.35603091 -0.36207399 -0.06543494]
```

How can I extract the information if it is stationary or not?

Comment: Null hypothesis: stationary. If $p$-value is small enough (say, below $0.05$) reject the null hypothesis; if not, do not reject.

Answer (score 6):

The problem in many test statistics with non-standard distributions is that the available p-values or critical values are available only for a restricted range. If the value is outside this range, then only the boundary value is reported and the actual p-value is somewhere above the upper limit or somewhere below the lower limit.

In this case, in the first two examples the reported p-value is at the upper bound 0.1, the actual p-value will be larger than 0.1, so we cannot reject the Null hypothesis of stationarity.
In the third case, the reported p-value is the lower bound of the range 0.01, and the actual p-value will be smaller than 0.01. So we can reject the Null hypothesis of stationarity with alpha 0.01.

Given that the warning is not printed in the second example, the warning might be set to be issued only once instead of each time. (Which would be a bug.)

Comment: Thanks so if I want to check that is stationary I could do: if p-value=0.1 then is stationary (or better I cannot reject the non-stationarity), otherwise it is not stationary

Comment: We reject stationarity if p-value < alpha, which is usually taken as 0.05. I wouldn't use an equality condition like `p_value == 0.1`, because the implementation of available p-values might change and the answer would become a floating point number. Eg. don't reject stationarity `if p_value >= 0.1`.